# General: how to validate a proposed system architecture?

Tags: validation, architecture, embedded, system

Good day,
I´m taking over a guy who started defining the architecture of a HW/SW communication tool. I´m in charge now to validate his progress so far, before writing all the specifications and implement it.

How can I formally proceed? Is there a methodology to validate a HW/SW architecture against intial top-level requirements?

Cheers,
Funky24

Comment: Sorry, but this is a place to solve problem but not a whole task.

Comment: This is a really generic question.  Please try to provide a more detailed question with some specifics.

Comment: I am not asking for the whole task to be solved, but only for a guidance. I´m aware that my question isn´t too specific, but I´m not yet into the implementation, and there is no stackexchange for systems engineering...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, your architecture is "valid" if it meets the set of top-level requirements that are architecturally significant to your stakeholders.

With that I mean that:

1. It's better not to assume that your list of requirements is complete or that they have been written correctly.
2. You need to make a selection of the most important requirements and focus on those.

In general the list from point 2 will generally include a majority of non-functional requirements (performance, usability, etc). Functional requirements are of course important, but they don't drive the architecture of a system.

A good formal methodology for architecture evaluation is [ATAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architecture_tradeoff_analysis_method) (for Architecture tradeoff analysis method) from SEI. You could have a look at their [technical report](http://www.sei.cmu.edu/reports/00tr004.pdf) and tailor it to your needs and to the size of the project. Since you have not designed the design, you may end up doing some *reverse-engineering* to figure out why certain choices were made.